# JS/jQuery: Detect when a video's muted property is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect when a user mutes/unmutes or changes the volume of a html video so the next time a page with a video is loaded the previous audio settings can be applied. I have been able to set the video's mute state using `$('video').prop('muted', sessionStorage.getItem('is-muted'));` but I am unsure how to detect when the user changes the mute state so I can store it for the next time a page is loaded. For example:

```
// This never fires
$('video').on('change', function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('is-muted', $(this).prop('muted'));
});
```

How can I detect when the video mute/volume level is changed so I can persist it in storage?

Comment: `$('video').on('click' ...)` ?

Comment: Wouldn't include keyboard shortcuts that can do things like change the volume level. I was hoping there was an easy way to just detect when the volume/muted was changed.

Comment: there is also `keypress` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `volumechange` event and check `prop`.

```
const video = $('video');

video.on('volumechange', (e) => {
  // check video.prop('muted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a W3Schools.com page which gives an example of getting and setting audio and video volume with the [DOM volume property](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp).

in traditional JavaScript:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.volume = 0.2;
```

To convert that to jQuery parlance in your case:

```
$('video').volume = 0.2;
```

If you have a look at the HTML 5.2 specification from W3C, specifically at the part about [Effective Media Volume](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#effective-media-volume), it appears that a user can override media volume with their user-agent:

> If the user has indicated that the user agent is to override the volume of the element, then the element’s effective media volume is the volume desired by the user. Abort these steps.

As well as many other possibly helpful HTML5 media properties.

Comment: Too slow, and not sure I even answered the question!